# Как не меняя размера кнопки вместить весь текст изменяя его textSize. в андроид

Tags: java, android, android-button

Здравия всем.
Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли в андроид встроенное свойство, подогнать размер текста кнопки, чтоб оно отображалось полностью не меняя размер кнопки?
Если все же писать самому, то как узнать длину отображаемого текста?
Или просто направьте на "путь истинный" ). Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Так как Button наследуется от TextView, то в нем можно использовать следующие атрибуты начиная с SDK 26 (Android 8+) и они прекрасно работают:

```
android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
android:autoSizeMinTextSize="..."
android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="..."
```

Как правило, необходимо установить минимальный размер текста.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую